# Requiring node modules in ionic + electron (5.0.0) desktop application

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, electron, ionic4

I'm building a desktop application using ionic and electron.

I started using `electron v4.1.3` and i was able to require node modules in the "ionic part" of the application, for example in the home.ts file by using:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

    ngOnInit () {
        console.log ((<any> window).require ("fs"));
    }
}
```

and this is what i get:

[image: Screen of ionic app default home page]

As you can see i can access all `fs` methods, so i can read, write, copy files and whatever else.

Now i have installed `electron v5.0.0`, i created the same application but i get an error when i try to require `fs` module in the `ngOnInit` method:

> window.require is not a function

[image: Screen of ionic app default home page with node module require error]

How can i fix this? If you need more details on installation or envinronment just tell me, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nodeIntegration is now disabled by default in 5.0.0 as per breaking changes document.

https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/breaking-changes.md#planned-breaking-api-changes-50

and the release notes

https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v5.0.0

So you need to enable it :

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true }
  });
```

Comment: Sure :) anytime